# infinite Dihedral group is unimodular

Tags: group-theory

How to show that the infinite Dihedral group is unimodular?

A locally compact group G is strongly amenable if, for every open
relatively compact neighborhood C of the unit which is symmetric we have
lim|C^(p+1)|/|C^p| = 1. where |.| is the left Haar measure

Is it true that the infinite Dihedral group is strongly amenable?